# A ball animation in simple harmonic motion using SDL2 and C++

Tags: c++, trigonometry, sdl-2

I'm trying to emulate the following ball. Notice the simple harmonic motion of the ball, with the very ends of the ball bounce having a smaller velocity compared to the velocity in the middle:

[image]

I'm able to implement a bouncing ball, however it's not simple harmonic motion:

[image]

The corresponding code is as follows:

```
Dot::Dot() {
//Initialize the offsets
mPosX = 300;
mPosY = 0;

//Initialize the velocity
mVelX = 0;
mVelY = 4;
}

void Dot::move() {

//Move the dot up or down
mPosY += mVelY;

//If the dot went too far up or down
if( ( mPosY < 0 ) || ( mPosY + DOT_HEIGHT > SCREEN_HEIGHT ) )
{
    //Move back
    mVelY = -mVelY;
    }
}
```

I have a simple harmonic motion model, like so:

[image]

The corresponding code is as follows:

```
Dot::Dot() {
//Initialize the offsets
mPosX = 300;
mPosY = 0;

//Initialize the velocity
mVelX = 0;
mVelY = 0;
}

void Dot::move() {
time_t current_time;
current_time = time(NULL);

mPosY = int(((460) - 10) * sin(2.4 * 2 * 3.141592 / 60 * current_time + (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) 
));

//const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480 
}
```

The issues with this implementation are that:

(1). the ball image appears every now and then, rather than continuously like in the blue ball model I tried to emulate at the very beginning

(2). the ball goes well beyond the top frame of the window, rather than slowing down at the very top of the window, again like the blue ball model.

For (2), I understand that I need to add a phase shift, i.e x in A*sin(wt + x), however changing this value doesn't do anything to prevent the ball from disappearing at the top of the window.

Any ideas on how to solve these issues?

Edit: I was able to solve (1) by doing += to mPosY rather than =, such as:

```
mPosY += int(4 * cos(2.4 * 2 * 3.141592 / 60 * current_time + (SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) ));
```

However, I'm still *unable to get the ball to bounce up and down within the frame of the window I created.*

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For pure-math-like questions (in this case you just want to have the math formula) they're not really on-topic here...

Comment: In your original code, sin(...) takes a value between -1 and 1 so the position takes values between -450 and 450. I guess you want the SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 bit outside of your arguments to sin(...). By the way, there are way too many parameters and the `int` bit is not necessary (conversion happens regardless).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using actual simple harmonic equations.
For example, if your display dimensions are (500, 500), the center Y is 250. from there say your equation is in the form of x = a*cos(n*t + m) + c where x is displacement (meters), a is amplitude n is for the period, for example the period (T) = 2PI/n t is time (seconds) and m is for phase shift and c is for the center. That way when you need the velocity of the object, you have a function that follows along the lines of

```
double Velocity(double time){
   double vel = derivative_of_displacement_equation(time);
   return vel;
}
```

And so in the program, you adjust the equation to suit the display dimensions, then you set the objects X/Y coordinates as the value returned from the displacement equation (PLUS THE CENTER OFFSET, in this example, if the center is at the middle of the screen, you would set the Y coordinate to the equation PLUS 250). Keep in mind coordinates begin at (0,0) so your displacement equation (at least the part where it involves the proportional factor, which in this case is time), you make that negative instead.

Here is some code that I believe answers your question:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

const double PI = 3.14159265358979;

void draw_circle(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int x, int y, int radius, SDL_Color color)
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
    for (int w = 0; w < radius * 2; w++)
    {
        for (int h = 0; h < radius * 2; h++)
        {
            int dx = radius - w; // horizontal offset
            int dy = radius - h; // vertical offset
            if ((dx*dx + dy*dy) <= (radius * radius))
            {
                SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x + dx, y + dy);
            }
        }
    }
}

double Displacement(double time, double a, double n, double m, double c)
{
    double displacement = a*cos(n*time + m) + c;
    return displacement;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("SHM", 0, 30, 500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL|SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);// | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );

    double timeDifference;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start, finish;
    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    finish = start;

    SDL_Event event;
    bool running = true;

    while (running){
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255,255,255,255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        finish = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        timeDifference = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish - start).count();
        timeDifference = timeDifference / 1000000000;

        ///The "-(250-20) is the center y (250) minus the radius of the circle (20), and its - out the front as negative a due to coordinates
        double yPosition = round( Displacement(timeDifference, -(250-20), 2, 0, 250 )  );
        draw_circle(renderer, 250, yPosition, 20, {255,0,0});

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want the velocity and acceleration, make another function that returns the gradient of the original displacement function (for velocity), and derivative of the velocity function (for acceleration) or just the second derivative of the displacement equation

Comment: For the comment on the original post, sin(...) doesn't take values between [-1, 1], it ```returns``` values between [-1, 1], ```asin(...)``` takes values in that range as it is an inverse function. You adjust the height using ```a``` in  my example, which is the amplitude.

Comment: I had an explanation before it, mustve deleted it. It's in the answer below

Comment: White space is a resource, save the environment and use it carefully. ;-)

Comment: Also keep in mind, in your displacement function, if it is dependent on velocity, acceleration is not the derivative anymore (with respect to time). acceleration is actually the derivative of (1/2 v^2) with respect to displacement. From there if you want velocity with respect to time you need to integrate using dv/dt. Also, if you want to go back, acceleration is also equal to  v dv/dx and you need to integrate again.

Answer (score 1):

In general you have `a0 + a/2*cos (2**t/T + )` where `a0` is the vertical position of the half of the vertical travel, `a` is the height of the travel, `t` is time, `T` the period ie., the time to do a complete cycle for going and coming back to the same state or uple { position, momentum }, and  the time shift, ie., the moment where the height is at zero of  the cos.

So if you want the ball to be on the floor at `t=0`, you want cos at the minimum, ie.,  `= -/2`.

You want to manage your position in function of your game's time `t`, so you can decouple the time to compute (which depend on your compute calpabilities) and the game's time (that you want constant from a machine to another).

Therefore you want:

```
auto VerticalPosition(double t)
-> double { return CorrectedScreenHeight/2*(1 + cos(2*PI*t/T + phi)); }
```

And you define `CorrectedScreenHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT - DOT_HEIGHT`, `T` and `phi` outside, as properties of your system.

Between two consecutive images, you increment `t`, in order to have the correct experienced time. Typically you have 60 images/s (WPF, DirectX, web, etc), hence a period of 1.0/60s between consecutive images, this goes in your function that modifies `t`. The speed of your ball then depend on `T`, that you can tune independently.